# Detect if Scrollable widget is scrolled manually or programatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is there a way to detect if a scroll in

1. `PageView` (`PageController`) or
2. `Scrollable` widget (`ScrollController`)

is done manually by a user or programatically using `jumpTo()` or `animateTo()` on the controller objects.

Wrapping the scrollable widget in a `NotificationListener` also does not give us any such callback or flag.

I found a solution around this but I find it a little hacky and would like to know if there is a better solution for it:

**My Solution:**
Wrap the `Scrollable` widget in a `GestureDetector` widget and use the `onTapUp` and `onTapDown` callback functions to and set a flag (`isScrollManual`) to check if the scroll is manual or programatically.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyPageControllers(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPageControllers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageControllersState createState() => _MyPageControllersState();
}

class _MyPageControllersState extends State<MyPageControllers> {

  PageController _controller1;
  bool isScrollManual = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller1 = PageController();

    _controller1.addListener(() {
      if(isScrollManual){
        /// Manual Scroll
      }else{
        /// Programmatic scroll
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (tapDownDetails){
          isScrollManual = true;
          setState(() {});
        },
        onTapUp: (tapUpDetails){
          isScrollManual = false;
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: PageView.builder(
          controller: _controller1,
          itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) =>
      Container(
        color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length],
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            index.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 60),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution I found was to wrap the `Scrollable` widget in a `GestureDetector` widget and use the `onTapUp` and `onTapDown` callback functions to and set a flag (`isScrollManual`) to check if the scroll is manual or programatically.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyPageControllers(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPageControllers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageControllersState createState() => _MyPageControllersState();
}

class _MyPageControllersState extends State<MyPageControllers> {

  PageController _controller1;
  bool isScrollManual = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller1 = PageController();

    _controller1.addListener(() {
      if(isScrollManual){
        /// Manual Scroll
      }else{
        /// Programmatic scroll
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (tapDownDetails){
          isScrollManual = true;
          setState(() {});
        },
        onTapUp: (tapUpDetails){
          isScrollManual = false;
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: PageView.builder(
          controller: _controller1,
          itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) =>
      Container(
        color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length],
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            index.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 60),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap in a `Listener` and with `onPointerUp` function you can detect when user just finished interaction with scrollable widget:

```
Listener(
    onPointerUp: (pointerUpEvent) {
        //interaction finished
    },
    child: PageView(),
),
```